# Tarifx.geo - Creating multiple georoutes

Tags: r, geocode, ggmap, drive

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to find the drive time between many zip codes. I am able to do so with `ggmap`, however the API load limit is 2,500. I need to run this for more and heard that Bing can help. I tried using `tarifx.geo`, which works for a single zip to zip drive, but I need each zip combination individually listed. Lets get to the examples:

Google:

```
require(ggmap)

from <- as.character(c("27205","48212"))
to <- as.character(c("54952","14450"))

driveTimes <- mapdist(from, to, mode='driving')

print(driveTimes)

   from    to       m       km   miles seconds  minutes     hours
1 27205 54952 1533077 1533.077 952.654   52716 878.6000 14.643333
2 48212 14450  555906  555.906 345.440   19700 328.3333  5.472222
```

^^ Notice the two drive times

taRifx.geo

When I use tarifx.geo, it looks at each zip code as a waypoint along a trip.

```
require("taRifx.geo")

from <- as.character(c("27205","48212"))
to <- as.character(c("54952","14450"))

combined <- data.frame(from, to)
combined[] <- lapply(combined, as.character)

for (i in 1:nrow(combined){
    driveTimes <- georoute( c(combined[i,1], combined[i,2]), 
                  verbose=TRUE,
                  returntype="time",
                  service="bing" )
}

print(driveTimes)
    time
1 21040
```

^^ Here I need it to print two rows for each zip to zip drive time.

Thanks in advance for your help! I've tried several methods defining the from/to, but I might be suffering from lack of sleep and can't see the problem right in front of me. If there is a better solution, please do tell. :)

Comment: Just store your zip codes in a data frame with a `from` and `to` column and do each one in a loop. If you don't understand what I just said you should read a basic R introduction so you know what a data frame and a loop are.

Comment: @Spacedman I took you advice and edited the code above. However, the `driveTimes` variable only stores the last iteration of the for loop. How can I fix that? Thanks!

Comment: I've tried wrapping with `rbind` with no success and also confirmed with `print(driveTimes)` that each zip to zip drive is calculating, but not being added as a new row in the results vector. Thanks again for the help. I'm not a total noob. Only a small one. :)

Comment: IGNORE. I got it... I just indexed the `driveTimes` vector. Thanks :)